Как задать параметр запуска игры на Unity, чтобы она при запуске спрашивала права администратора?
Я хотел сделать, чтобы когда пользователь открывает мою скомпилированную игру в Unity, то игра бы спрашивала права администратора перед открытием игры. В самом Unity я не видел что-либо, что могло бы это как-то включить.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

REVOLUT1ON, вот справка, как задать вопрос на ru.SO https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Нужно сделать конфигурационный  файл "unityplayer.dll.config", где пропишите следующие:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <application>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </application>
</configuration>


И куда мне нужно будет добавлять этот unityplayer.dll.config?

где находится исполняемый файл вашей игры (UnityPlayer.dll)

Я попробовал это сделать только что, у меня не запрашиваются всё-также права администратора при запуске игры.

тогда я без понятия, я делал так и у меня работало
